# MFC, using vs2008 with dll that maintained at VS2015

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2008, mfc

**The Problem**

I have a dll compiled under VS2015.

I have a source code(that using the above dll) at VS2008.

The project compiled but not running (get run time error). 
when i try to debug it, i got error at CDialog::OnInitdialog()
i got the follow exception:

Unhandled exception at 0x788b2db6 (mfc90u.dll) in prog.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

i try to update my project to 2015 and its work well, but for compatibility with other project i need to run it under vs2008.

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: Mixing up DLLs compiled with a different compiler s a bad idea. Don't do it. Compile your DLL with VS2008 is you want to use it with a project compiled under VS2008.

Comment: I guess you have access to the source code from the .dll compiled with VS2015? If you do, might wanna share it here as there might be an obvious coding mistake. Did you actually do some unit testing and narrowed the problem down to the compiler difference?
Tried compiling your project with VS2015 or the .dll with VS2008 and vice-versa?

Comment: @Vinzenz  -- If both dll and app are compiled with same version its ok. The isuue I want to take the dll to 2015 but there are still some sources that maintained under 2008.